# Is it possible to make a function to compare dynamically selected variables from a vector of objects?

Tags: c++, function, object, compare, member

I keep coming into situations where I want to be able to make a single function to cover the similar tasks.

EDIT:

The kind of task in mind is to compare member variables between object. It would be excellent if there was a way to write one function that allowed you to give the objects as arguments, and the particular member variable to compare as another argument. This would require some way of representing or identifying the particular member variable I would like to compare on each call of the function.

Here is an example class and objects to illustrate what I mean:

```
class MyObject {
  int var1;
  int var2;
  int var3;

  // Unwritten constructor that sets all member variables in order
};

MyObject obj1 (1, 2, 3);
MyObject obj2 (4, 3, 2);
```

Here is an example of a set of similar functions that would be nice to be able to merge into one, with dynamic selection of which member variable is used:

```
int compareMemberVar1 (MyObject obj1, MyObject obj2) {

  return max(obj1.var1, obj2.var1);
}

int compareMemberVar2 (MyObject obj1, MyObject obj2) {

  return max(obj1.var2, obj2.var2);
}

int compareMemberVar3 (MyObject obj1, MyObject obj2) {

  return max(obj1.var3, obj2.var3);
}
```

These would obivously be used like so:

```
int var1max = compareMemberVar1 (obj1, obj2);
int var2max = compareMemberVar2 (obj1, obj2);
int var3max = compareMemberVar2 (obj1, obj2);
```

Here is the sort of function I'd like to be able to write to replace the above 3:

```
int compareAnyMemberVar (MyObject obj1, MyObject obj2, /*representation of memberVar*/) {

  return max(obj1./*memberVar*/, obj2./*memberVar*/);
}
```

And it's corresponding mock usage:

```
int var1max = compareAnyMemberVar (obj1, obj2, /*representation of Var1*/);
int var2max = compareAnyMemberVar (obj1, obj2, /*representation of Var2*/);
int var3max = compareAnyMemberVar (obj1, obj2, /*representation of Var3*/);
```

EDIT:

In the above, I am trying to use the same function to compare a different member variable on each call. So the /*representation of VarX*/ part would be some way of representing or identifying the member variable I want to access this time.

Is this possible? And how? Thanks in advance for any help offered,

Pete

Comment: Are you looking for function pointers? I'm not finally sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: I can see why my question is confusing. I guess a simpler explanation of what I'm after is, a way to represent/identify a member variable of an object. This representation or identification could then be passed to functions or otherwise to access the particular member variable desired that time. I'll edit my question and try and make it clearer

Comment: There are also member variable pointers available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use member pointers:

```
template<typename T>
int compareAnyMemberVar(MyObject obj1, MyObject obj2, T MyObject::* member) {
    return max(obj1.*member, obj2.*member);
}

int var1max = compareAnyMemberVar(obj1, obj2, &MyObject::var1);
int var2max = compareAnyMemberVar(obj1, obj2, &MyObject::var2);
int var3max = compareAnyMemberVar(obj1, obj2, &MyObject::var3);
```

---

Generalised further:

```
template<typename T, class C>
int compareAnyMemberVar(C const& obj1, C const& obj2, T C::* member) {
    return max(obj1.*member, obj2.*member);
}
```

Comment: @molbdnio gave a very similar answer but without he template bit, is there a particular benefit to using the template?

Comment: @IronAttorney it's just more general. If you added a string member for instance this function would still work.

Comment: Ah! Well that covers my next trail of thought too. Awesome! And I assume I could expand this yet further by making a template for an object or something could I? That way I could make one function to compare any member variable of any object

Comment: @IronAttorney i don't understand. You mean change `template<typename T>` to `template<typename T, class C>` and change `T MyObject::* member` to `T C::*member`? Yes that would work.

Comment: Yep! That's the kind of thing I mean. You're awesome! Time to learn about templates :D Thanks for all the info above and beyond!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a "pointer-to-member".

A pointer to an `int` member of `MyObject` has the type `int MyObject::*`.
`MyObject::*` means "pointer to a member of `MyObject`".
(It's not a "normal" pointer in that it doesn't designate an absolute location in memory, but that's beside the point here. There's plenty of reading material in both books and internets.)

You create them like this, with the "address-of" operator:

```
int MyObject::* mvar1 = &MyObject::var1;
int MyObject::* mvar2 = &MyObject::var2;
```

and to dereference them, you use the `.*` operator:

```
MyObject obj1 = ...
MyObject obj2 = ...
if (obj1.*mvar1 == obj2.*mvar2)
    // ...

int compareAnyMemberVar (MyObject obj1, MyObject obj2, int MyObject::* member) {

  return max(obj1.*member, obj2.*member);
}

// ...
int x = compareAnyMemberVar(obj1, obj2, &MyObject::var3);
```

If you have a pointer to an object, you dereference with the even more amusing `->*` operator.

```
MyObject* op = ...
int v = op->*mvar2;
```

Comment: Can you also use member references?

Comment: @IronAttorney there are no member references (i.e. `int MyObject::&` is not allowed).

Comment: Fair play, I suppose this usage of pointers probably isn't that dangerous anyway